# creating a new variable according to existing variables using R

Tags: r, variables

I would like to create a new variable with the values to be determined by the corresponding values of two existing variables. My data set is similar to the one below:

```
aid <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
temp <- c(38,39,NA,41,NA)
surv1 <- c(5,8,0,6,9)
data <- data.frame(aid,temp,surv1)
```

Now, I would like to create a new variable called surv2.
That is, if temp is NA then surv2 should also be an NA;
and if temp is not NA then surv2 should take the value of surv1

```
#The final data should look like this:
aid <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
temp <- c(38,39,NA,41,NA)
surv1 <- c(5,8,0,6,9)
surv2 <- c(5,8,NA,6,NA)
```

Comment: baz - I removed the "" around the NA's so that R correctly interpreted them as not available and not as the character string "NA".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifelse` evaluates a condition (whether or not `temp` is NA) in an element by element fashion. We will test whether or not temp is NA and assign the resulting value as NA or surv1 depending on the outcome.

```
data$surv2 <- with(data, ifelse( is.na(temp), NA, surv1))
```

Comment: ! Thanks alot for that. I was using this script: data$surv2 <- ifelse(is.na(data$temp,NA,data$surv1) but it did not work because it was reading "NA" as a character string. After you mention it, I removed the "" from NAs and it worked and gave the same output. The "" was not intentional but it gave me what I did not want. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept it as such. :)

Comment: @Roman, yes, indeed and just used it because it gave me what I wanted and am accepting it as such.